# Getting the sum of even numbers (from 1-10) from an array MIPS

Tags: arrays, mips

I'm new to MIPS and i'm getting a bit discouraged, this is my first task at it and I already feel stuck. I can't seem to find the problem.

```
.data
    myArray: .space 40
.text
    #For later to check if the number is even 
    addi $s2, $zero, 2

    #values for the array
    addi $t0, $zero, 1
    addi $t1, $zero, 2
    addi $t2, $zero, 3
    addi $t3, $zero, 4
    addi $t4, $zero, 5
    addi $t5, $zero, 6
    addi $t6, $zero, 7
    addi $t7, $zero, 8
    addi $t8, $zero, 9
    addi $t9, $zero, 10

    #initial index
    addi $s1, $zero, 0

    #putting the values in an array
    sw $t0, myArray($s1)
        addi $s1, $s1, 4
    sw $t1, myArray($s1)
        addi $s1, $s1, 4
    sw $t2, myArray($s1)
        addi $s1, $s1, 4
    sw $t3, myArray($s1)
        addi $s1, $s1, 4
    sw $t4, myArray($s1)
        addi $s1, $s1, 4
    sw $t5, myArray($s1)
        addi $s1, $s1, 4
    sw $t6, myArray($s1)
        addi $s1, $s1, 4
    sw $t7, myArray($s1)
        addi $s1, $s1, 4
    sw $t8, myArray($s1)
        addi $s1, $s1, 4
    sw $t9, myArray($s1)
        addi $s1, $s1, 4

    #cleaning
    addi $s1, $zero, 0
    addi $s0, $zero, 0

    loop:
        beq $s1, 40, exit
        addi $s1, $s1, 4


        lw $s3, myArray($s1)



        div $s3, $s2
        mfhi $s4

        beqz $s4, true


        j loop
    true:
        add $s0, $s0, $s3
        j loop
    exit:
        move $a0, $s0
        syscall
```

I would really appreciate getting help for this problem, also some suggestions for understanding mips more and sources for learning.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what the 'problem' is.

Any reason you don't start with an array that already has the data in it ?

```
myArray:  .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

You need to set the main label

```
  .text
  .globl main

 main:

  # the code
```

For the loop for the checking if its even:

```
loop:
    beq $s1, 40, exit
    addi $s1, $s1, 4
```

This will increment s1 by 4 **before** you use it, so you are not getting the first value. so need to move the add part to **after** where you get the current array value.

For the check if it is even, or could do an and of the values bottom bit - if set its odd, otherwise its event

So

```
div $s3, $s2
mfhi $s4
```

could be changed to

```
and $s4, $s3,
```